# Revolution Slider Drupal works only when I'm logged in as admin

Tags: drupal-7, revolution-slider

I have this website http://clil.ea.gr and for some reason I can't figure out, revolution slider works only when I log in as admin. As a visitor loops the loading gif. Tried with permissions, cleared cash, nothing.
Any ideas?

Comment: Picture are in public folder ? Revolution slider is a content type (check permission for anoymous user) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try different module for your project ?
Please find below links of modules which are more frequent.

Slick : https://www.drupal.org/project/slick
Flexslider : https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider

Comment: If I won't manage to figure this out I will, but it's really weird because I use it in manu other websites and never had such an issue.